# Biber (texlive) tells me "Cant open nul: no such file or directory"

Tags: texlive, biber

I got texlive 2020 and biber used to run fine. Now after a while of not using it, everytime i start biber it says **"Cant open nul: no such file or directory"**. The command `where biber` gives me the correct path, but `biber --help` gives the above error.

Im on win10 and admin. Only one account on this machine. I deleted all temp files ( i read that some cache biber uses is there, but that didnt change anything). I also used `TAKEOWN` and `ICACLS` on the Temp folder, nothing changed.

Then i tried to upgrade my texlive distribution to 2021 and also get an error when trying to run the installer, pretty much the same error: **The System cannot find the file**, after it tries to run "starting the main installer".

Do i have some problem with windows in general? Not sure what to do. Anybody got an idea? Installing other software works fine.

Thanks

Comment: did you delete the cache you get with biber --cache?

Comment: @Johnny195 What does running `reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\Null" /v "Start"` show on your system?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer biber --cache doesnt work as well. it gives the same error as biber --help.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\Null
    Start    REG_DWORD    0x4

Comment: @Johnny195 Try running `sc start Null` (might need administrator privileges) and then try again. If it works, run `sc config Null start= system` to make the change permanent.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger `sc start Null` doesnt work. Error 1058, service is deactivated or not connected.

Comment: @Johnny195 Then you have to run `sc config Null start= system` first (to activate it) and then either reboot or use `sc start Null`.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger that did the trick. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The error "Cant open nul: no such file or directory" indicates that the file `nul` does not exists. This is weird, since `nul` is a device file which should always exists on Windows, so the most likely reason for this is that the device driver controlling it (called "Null") has been disabled for some reason. Some programs expect this driver to work correctly, so it should be reenabled:

Run (with administrator privileges) the command

```
sc config Null start= system
```

to tell your system to start "Null" with the system (This is the default setting in Windows). Afterwards you have to reboot or run `sc start Null` to start `Null` immediately.